# Creating a template

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way in knockoutjs to create a knockout template, but inject further HTML depending on values passed to it.

Example:

```
<script type="text/html" id="userMessageTemplate">
    <div class="chatContent">
        <span data-bind="text: userName"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: userMessageAlert "></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

This template currently has two span tags each bind to userName and userMessgeeAllert properties from the model respectfully.

Now I decide to use this template somewhere else but instead of userName I want it bind to orderNo, and also Add another span tag called Address:

```
<script type="text/html" id="userMessageTemplate">
    <div class="chatContent">
        <span data-bind="text: OrderNo"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: userMessageAlert "></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Address "></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

At the moment I would just create another template as above.  But I would like to inject values, and based on those values create a template on the fly:

```
function (orderNo, userMessageAllert,Address)
{
// now based on the values create template 
}
```

Comment: Your templates don't have much in common. Why don't you just create two templates? It would be simpler and easier to read

Comment: Avoid the need to create loads of templates.  The solution I have to to create a javascript createTemplateFunction taking in the values, such as Address, OrderNo. Then have some code that create a span tag for each value, setting its data-bind attribute

Comment: Well you could use the `if` binding, it would still be more readable

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you could fix it by passing an array of properties to the template, and using a foreach-binding.

```
<script type="text/html" id="userMessageTemplate">
    <div class="chatContent" data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

In general, I would have a look at [Knockout components](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html). Not out yet, but will be soon, and it allows you to pass data into your template, to which it can respond intelligently.